# Symfony 4 Environment variable not found composer install

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm completly new to Symfony and tried the following guide: https://github.com/thecodingmachine/symfony-vuejs ... but without docker (I have a simple webspace, I can't use docker there).

Now I'm stuck right in the beginning, when calling `composer install` in the app root. I get the following message:

```
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 131:
    Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL".
```

Well, that sounds easy, I have to setup an enviroment variable ... but I'm not using docker and I don't want to set up a temporarly variable in the shell. Few seconds of google helped me, that I can use `.env` for my problem like descriped here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables

In the example project is already a `.env` file, so I extendet it by `DATABASE_URL`. But suddenly it is not taking that variable.

I'm working on a macbook with a simple apache/php setup without forther configuration.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a working database? The url could look something like this: `DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"`

Comment: my variable looks like this: `DATABASE_URL='mysql://$MYSQL_USER:$MYSQL_PASSWORD@localhost:3306/$MYSQL_DATABASE'` but I would think that I get another message, if it can't connect to the databse

Comment: there is your issue; use *double quotes*  vars are usually only parsed in there